# Bootstrap 4: Bottom border only on li elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm making a sidebar that needs to have a bottom border after every li element, except the last one. But Bootstrap 4 already has borders on list-group-items and if I add border-0 it removes them completely. And I can't seem to figure out how to edit this via CSS so it works. It only displays one bottom border after the last li element.

Here's a quick image preview of what I'm trying to make:

[image]

And here's my code:

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100vw;
    width: 90px;
    top: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    .list-group-item {
      border: 0;
    }
    a {
      color: gray;
      font-size: 16px;
      span {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    }
  }
  .menu:hover {
    width: 260px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
      <ul class="list-group flex-column d-inline-block menu">
        <li class="list-group-item py-2">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="align-middle"><img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" height="50" class="mr-4">Text</span>
          </a>
        </li> <!-- /.list-group-item -->
        
        <li class="list-group-item py-2">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="align-middle"><img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" height="50" class="mr-4">Text</span>
          </a>
        </li> <!-- /.list-group-item -->
        
        <li class="list-group-item py-2">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="align-middle"><img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" height="50" class="mr-4">Text</span>
          </a>
        </li> <!-- /.list-group-item -->
        
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- /.sidebar -->
```

Comment: Oh, okay! I'll add the SCSS tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the border only for that .list-group-item that is inside your `.menu` and you can also use the `:last-child` selector to set the bottom-border of the last li element to 0:

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 90px;
  top: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu .list-group-item {
  border-bottom: 1px;
}
.menu .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.menu a {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.menu a span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu:hover {
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="sidebar">
      <ul class="list-group flex-column d-inline-block menu">
        <li class="list-group-item py-2">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="align-middle"><img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" height="50" class="mr-4">Text</span>
          </a>
        </li> <!-- /.list-group-item -->
        
        <li class="list-group-item py-2">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="align-middle"><img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" height="50" class="mr-4">Text</span>
          </a>
        </li> <!-- /.list-group-item -->
        
        <li class="list-group-item py-2">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="align-middle"><img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" height="50" class="mr-4">Text</span>
          </a>
        </li> <!-- /.list-group-item -->
        
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- /.sidebar -->
```

Comment: Yes, but what about those default borders Bootstrap 4 adds? How can I remove them and only have bottom borders as that image preview shows?

Answer (score 1):

```
<h5 class="card-title">This should work (No css needed)</h5>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">First</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Seccond</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) to change any styles of the last item

```
.list-group-item:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::last-child` on ul li:

```
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100vw;
    width: 90px;
    top: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    .list-group-item:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    a {
      color: gray;
      font-size: 16px;
      span {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    }
  }
  .menu:hover {
    width: 260px;
  }
```